# Regex replace 2 or more dashes with one dash

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I have used many Regex to do this, but the problem is i want to consider also:

```
abc- -abc   //should output abc-abc
abc -- abc  //should output abc - abc
abc- - abc  //should output abc- abc
abc - -abc  //should output abc -abc
```

I have used:

```
String x=x.replaceAll("[\\-*]{2,}","-");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
-(\\s*-)+
```

- `-`: matches `-` literally.
- `(...)+`: grouping (1+ times)
- `\\s*-`: matches `-` optionally space (`\s`) prepended

---

```
x = x.replaceAll("-(\\s*-)+", "-");
```